# What's the best way to remove some of the builtin yasnippet and make emacs upgradable?

Tags: yasnippet

I have custom yasnippets and I noticed they are located in the ~/.emacs.d/snippets folder. The builtin snippets are located at ~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20161008.804. There are some builtin snippets which I don't want and I want to remove them. Can I simply remove them? Will next time I upgrade yasnippet cause them come back again? What's the best way to handle it?

Please don't suggest not to remove them. I really don't want them because of the conflict key and poor quality of them.

Thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change the value of the variable `yas-snippet-dirs`, which by default includes `yas-installed-snippets-dir` (pointing to the builtin snippets - those that you want ignored/disabled). For example:

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/mysnippets"))
```

... asuming you have your own custom snippets at the above location (or at least the empty folder created for such a purpose).

See also the documentation of that variable for more details (basically, it's a list of paths pointing to snippet folders, and the first path is used to store snippets created with `yas-new-snippet`).